# C1x: When will it land, what to expect?

Tags: c, language-features, c11

C99 still isn't supported by many compilers, and much of the focus is now on C++, and its upcoming standard C++1x.

I'm curious as to what C will "get" in its next standard, when it will get it, and how it will keep C competitive. C and C++ are known to feed on one another's improvements, will C be feeding on the C++1x standard?

What can I look forward to in C's future?

Comment: Is there even a push for another C revision? Anything further I can think of that someone might want in C is actually a hint that they should move to a higher-level language...

Comment: No C still plays a very important role. I'm interested in what changes are planned to keep it applicable and up to date. Becoming higher level I don't think is part of that.

Comment: I never said it didn't. But I fail to see what is necessary to keep it "applicable" or "up to date". Most software still runs on infrastructure written in C, and that's not going to change anytime soon.

Comment: Yes, so any future changes are naturally of great interest :)

Comment: A summary of greater detail than Wikipedia would be nice. The draft is such a bore to read.

Comment: @Nicholas Knight - I think it's a lot of little things that recently-raised programmers miss, not huge sweeping changes. eg. the ability to have a typed compile-time-constant qualifier. It's become a de-facto standard to litter code with things like `#define NUM_THINGOS 8`, so we don't even notice it any more. But it makes me cringe to do it, and it'd be nice to be able to do `ctconst size_t NUM_THINGOS 8`.

Comment: Also, if **I** know how many thingos are in that static array, why can't the compiler? I just told it in little sqare brackets! Why can't I use the number of values of that enum I just declared instead of adding a dummy end value? I mean, these are all little annoyances, but they're all compile-time-fixable idiosyncrasies, the fixing of which would have no runtime effect.

Comment: @detly: compile-time const is a valid compiler optimization if done correctly, the compiler does know how big your static array is (try sizeof() on it), and I think you're using enums wrong. Sounds to me like you want things that are either already there, or shouldn't be in the first place.

Comment: @Nicholas Knight - you cannot, for example, declare a static array with a `const` size, only a compile time constant. Same with case labels, I think. `sizeof` I should have known, silly me. It's not uncommon to want to iterate over all values of an enumerated type.

Comment: Anyway, I don't want to start a flamewar about this, my point was that it's possible to tweak the language without making changes that would necessitate using a "high-level" language.

Comment: There hardly are any "higher level" languages, just ones with more features tacked on. The ones that are significantly improved are the ones that practically nobody uses.

Comment: @XTL: C has some warts. It could be possible to fix them and make other improvements to the language now that 40 years have passed, but little has changed in about 25 years. Of course there are plenty of reasons for this, but one can dream.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [ISO/IEC 9899:2011 standard](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=57853), aka C11, was published in [December 2011](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/).

The latest draft is [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf); I'm not aware of any differences between it and the final standard. There's already a Technical Corrigendum fixing an oversight in the specification of `__STDC_VERSION__` (now `201112L`) and the optional `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` (now `201112L`).

Answer (score 6):

I was typing a list of of features, but noticed the [Wikipedia page on C1X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C1X) has a pretty complete listing of all proposed changes.

On the ISO C working group posts 'after meeting' mailings on their [website](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/). One of the more interesting is this [Editor's Report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1495.pdf).

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing more detail than the Wikipedia page provides. Especially about the new character types. Will there be a whole family of functions to manipulate strings of these types (ala `strstr`, etc.) or just the functions for converting back and forth to multibyte strings? As for threads, is the only addition the `__thread` keyword? Or might there be a new portable threads API with less complexity and more sanity than POSIX threads?

Comment: On top of that, I wonder how C1x threads and POSIX threads might interact. It would be very unfortunate if the underlying implementation could not be the same, accessed either through the simple API which would be implemented across a range of systems (C1x) or the feature-rich API just available on POSIX environments.

Comment: I think it's highly likely it's an interface wrapper, and a subset or exact replica of pthreads.

Comment: Nobody would use C's threads if they were wildly different to POSIX threads, which are already widely used, documented and understood.

Comment: I've heard the C1x and C++11 worked hard to synchronize their thread models and atomics.  @R They added the _Atomic keyword.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a summary from the Wikipedia page:

- Alignment specification (`_Align` specifier, `alignof` operator, `aligned_alloc` function)
- Multithreading support (`_Thread_local` storage-class specifier, `<threads.h>` header including thread creation/management functions, mutex, condition variable and thread-specific storage functionality)
- Improved Unicode support (`char16_t` and `char32_t` types for storing UTF-16/UTF-32 encoded data, including the corresponding u and U string literal prefixes and conversion functions in `<uchar.h>`)
- Removal of the `gets` function
- Bounds-checking interfaces (Annex K)
- Analyzability features (Annex L)

Comment: Good riddance to `gets()`.

Comment: dreamlax: Indeed, I was going to put "*yay!*" after that item, but thought it might be in poor taste...

Comment: In the latest draft we get _Generic! A manual version of C++'s function overloading.

Comment: @Joe D: Type generics look awesome.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the best place to find the current status would be to look at the [latest draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) of the new version of the C standard. Warning: though it's coming directly from the committee, the server behind that link isn't always the most responsive...

Answer (score 4):

I looks like gcc as of 4.6 is [starting](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html) to look at C1x.  They claim to have:

- Static assertions (_Static_assert keyword)
- Typedef redefinition
- New macros in <float.h>
- Anonymous structures and unions