# What does C1x inherit from C++?

Tags: c++, c, c11

It is well known that both C++ takes features from C but that C also standardizes C++ features. C1x has gained full expression temporaries (previously it only had sequence point temporaries). C1x also took from the C++11 threading effort.

I wonder what other features C1x took from C++?

Comment: +1. I also like to know that.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341001/c1x-when-will-it-land-what-to-expect

Comment: [This wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C1X) seems to be nice link. Though, I don't know what is the motivation behind C1x to exist.

Comment: Guys this question doesnt wanna know "when will it land what can i expect?". You suppose anyone knows what of those expected features were inherited from C++! I at least have no clue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The threading part of C1x (5.1.2.4) is taken almost literally from C++11. Terms like *"conflict"* and *"atomic operations"* have identical definitions, for all practical purposes.

Alignment is also inspired by C++11: the keyword is `alignof`, and the maximum aligned type is `max_align_t` (dropping the `std::` namespace, of course).

Answer (score 8):

Some similarities include:

- static assertions: `_Static_assert ( constant-expression , string-literal );`
- atomic support
- unicode support - adds some typedefs (e.g. `char16_t`=`uint_least16_t`), literals, and utilities.
- `_Generic`

`_Generic` is really more like overloading than what we have with the power of templates. The ubiquitous example of `_Generic` is:

```
#define cbrt(X) _Generic((X), long double: cbrtl, \
                              default: cbrt, \
                              float: cbrtf)(X)
```

..but I'm not sure which were inherited expressly from C++.

Comment: *generics*? You mean template?

Comment: @Nawaz: no, it's called generics, and it's an ugly feature meant to be used where function overloading is used in C++ for years. E.g. if you want to write `sin(x)` to call the correct `sin` depending on whether `x` is `float`, `double` or `long double`.

Comment: @Nawaz ybungalobill answered this well =) but I will throw an example up to reduce confusion.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Thanks for the mini introduction. Can C1x's generic be used for generic implementation of data structures, such as Stack, Queue etc?

Comment: @Nawaz: No. They are not templates.

Comment: They can be used to fake explicit specializations of `void*`-based data structures. With lots and lots of macros.

Comment: `_Generic` doesn't have anything to do with C++. For example, C has tgmath.h since before.

Comment: @kaizer.se i wouldn't call tgmath first class or user extensible support of the same features. tgmath is more for fortran compatibility, and are implementation defined (e.g. via compiler extensions). `_Generic` is standardised, compiler independent, user defined overloading (and such).

Comment: As you see in your example, with `_Generic`, tgmath.h can be implemented in ISO C again. Anyway, it's not taken from C++ at all, unlike for example atomics which were co-developed with both C++ and C1x in mind.